# Vim color scheme does not cover whole background

Tags: macos, vim, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using Zsh with agnoster theme and Vim.

When I try to change the color scheme of Vim, a bottom and left of screen are not applied by color scheme. First screenshot is before changing color scheme and the second id after changing color scheme. How can i fix this?
[image: before chaging color scheme]
[image: after changing color scheme]

Answer (score 1):

The left part is because that is the background of the LineNr column.  You can change this with `hi LineNr ctermbg=xxx`.

The bottom is because vim isn't drawn in the whole screen in fullscreen mode.  Unfortunately you can only fix this by changing the background in your terminal emulator's preferences to match vim's new background colour.